# Import a local pdf file in vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to import a local pdf file in my vue project (bootstrapped using vue-cli@latest, using default config) but vue tries to parse it and gives this error:

```
./src/assets/myFile.pdf 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I just want to make the file available for download from a button click so I don't need to parse it but I need it to go through webpack so that the filename will get hashes, hence I want to avoid putting it in public folder and use `env.BASE_URL`.
Here the my `.vue` file for the component.

```
<template>
  <div class="root">
    <a
      v-bind:href="MyPdf"
      download='Something.pdf'
    >
      Download as pdf
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import MyPdf from '../assets/my.pdf';

  export default {
    name: "PdfDownload",
    data: function () {
      return { MyPdf }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  ...
</style>
```

I found similar questions on SO, but none of the answers solve the problem. I only solution I found was on vue docs to use `public` folder but I don't want that because I want hashes in filename. I am new to vue, I come from React, and in React you can simply import a pdf, word etc. file in js and use it in `href` of `a` and users can view/download it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to import it. Just create a `<a>` tag with correct URL to your pdf file. 
You can check if the path is correct downloading directly in the browser before.

Edit:
 In case you are facing the same problem and you are using webpack, you have to make sure you are using a loader for the `pdf` extension. In this case, the user was using vue-cli, and the way to change webpack config is on `vue.config.js`. I created a [gist](http://gist.github.com/aquilesb/f65bda1a8f96e82f73e6f95cedb09625) to show how add it.

Comment: It is simple like create an image. If you are using vue-cli, it will be something like
`<a href="/assets/my.pdf">download pdf</a>`. On vue-cli you can access your `assets` folder directly by `/assets/` in your application. You can try opening in the browser `http://localhost:{{PORT}}/assets/my.pdf`

Comment: Sorry, I almost forgot, on vue-cli or any other project using webpack, to load a pdf you have to add pdf loader rule. Otherwise, webpack won't understand that extension of file. I created a gist to show you how.  https://gist.github.com/aquilesb/f65bda1a8f96e82f73e6f95cedb09625. In this example I am presuming you have your pdfs on the folder: `src/assets/pdf/`

Comment: works like a charm thanks. It would be nice if you could put the vue config code from your gist in the actual answer so that future readers don't have to go to an external website.

Comment: How do I know the link to my pdf? `http://localhost:8080/assets` is a blank html page for me, rather than a folder. I tried importing it in `router.js` but I get this error message: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders" even though I have put the gist you created in my `vue.config.js`

Comment: Thanks, I had a `babel.config.js` file. In order to make it work I recomend to create the `vue.config.js` file at the root of the project folder and serve it again.