# error while opening pdf file in vue.js from local project folders

Tags: vue.js, pdf, gridsome

I'm working on a portfolio website and I need to open a `resume.pdf` file from local files when a button is clicked but I cant make it work. I'm using `gridsome` and vue.js. I tried this code initially:

```
<a class="cv-button float-right"
              href="../assets/resume.pdf"
              target="_blank">MY CV</a>
```

But when I hit the link(button) I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /src/assets/resume.pdf
```

and the url it goes to is:

```
http://localhost:8080/src/assets/resume.pdf
```

The problem I'm facing has been asked before:
[Opening a PDF file in another window with VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517942/opening-a-pdf-file-in-another-window-with-vuejs)
and [Open a PDF using VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760250/open-a-pdf-using-vuejs). 

 I tried to use the solutions provided but none of them actually worked and I got almost the same error every time! I have no problem loading images but this pdf file just doesn't work. The file is located in `src -> assets -> resume.pdf`. Please note that I tried many methods open the file but all failed, including using vue.js `methods` and `windos.open()` in javascript or the `required` keyword or using different ways to give the path of the source file such add `@/assets/resume.pdf` etc.

 below is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio.farzinnasiri.com",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gridsome build",
    "develop": "gridsome develop",
    "explore": "gridsome explore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@gridsome/source-filesystem": "^0.6.2",
    "@gridsome/transformer-remark": "^0.5.0",
    "gridsome": "^0.7.0",
    "vue-typer": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

and the preview of the website is here:http://farzinnasiri.ir. Of course I haven't yet added the pdf file but theoretically when some one hits the `MY CV` button, he/she should be directed to the resume file in the browser...

on last thing is that I couldn't find the pdf file in the final builded project(`dist` folder) so maybe vue.js can't read the file in the first place!

 Please give me some help here. Thank you for your attention

Comment: This post will likely help you to do what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925249/import-a-local-pdf-file-in-vue-project/56927934#56927934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, So i fixed the problem in `gridsome` by simply putting my pdf files in the `static` directory which `gridsome` makes when the project is created.  Gridsome puts every thing from that folder directly to the `dist/` folder so I just needed to give it a path like:

```
<g-link class="cv-button float-right" href="/resume.pdf" target="_blank">MY CV</g-link>
```

Comment: Note: Anything that isn't in `static/` will be compiled by the build tools - so this is the correct approach to this!